# Yii2 grid view row order / rank like SerialColumns

Tags: yii2

Is there a Yii2 embedded function that I can use as a rank/index. I have a list of models sorted by time_total ASC. I use SerialColumn as a rank for all the items, however the index is changing each time after filter or sort.

I need to keep the rank/index fixed for the set of data even after sorting or filtering.

Comment: Can you show your search model

Answer (score 1):

It could be done in the controller very easy, the first time you load the page, store all the values of `time_total` in a hashed array by the id of the row and then store them in a temporal table.

Then in the search that populates the models and fills the grid, place a join with that temporal table and sort by the value of that temporal table.

Im missing certain minor points, like where to do the join or not, or when to sort by temp table and where not, but nothing critical.

Of course you would sort and filter with ajax, so you could keep a logic inside the controller that checks if action `isAjax` and so, apply one logic or other.